# Error while creating table from CREATE_ERROR_LOG

Tags: exception, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am getting error when I am trying to create the error log table using DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG.

Error Message: table or view does not exist.

```
Begin
dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'table_name');
End;
```

I also tried -

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'table_name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you - instead of `table_name` - use real table name?

You:

```
SQL> Begin
  2  dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'table_name');
  3  End;
  4  /
Begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1179
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ERRLOG", line 225
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Me:

```
SQL> Begin
  2  dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'EMP');
  3  End;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

(table `EMP` actually exists in this schema).

Comment: Yes. I used the real table name. I am using this error logging for my insert statement inside the procedure.

Comment: I got the same errors as you are getting when you tried with Table_Name

Comment: Could you edit the original question you posted and *prove* that table you're talking about really exists in your schema? Run this: `select object_name, object_type from user_objects where upper(object_name) = upper('emp');`. Please, don't post *fake* table name. I'd like to see what you **really** have. (of course, you wouldn't use `emp` if that's not the table you're working with)

Comment: In my understanding we are allowed to give table name that is suitable as per the coding naming convention. In Oracle documents, I didn't see any such restriction that says that the table name must exist in the schema. The only restriction here is that the procedure will add ERR$_ and read 25 characters of the name that user is trying to give.

Comment: Reading your last comment, I'd say that you misunderstood what you read. Just to test it, try to run that piece of code by providing table name that exists in your schema. What is the result?

Comment: I created a test table first and then I used it inside the create_error_log procedure. The procedure got executed and table is also created. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So here we can conclude that we cannot use any random table name inside the create_error_log procedure. The table name should be similar to the one which is being used in insert statement. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not *similar*, but *exactly the same*. If you're inserting data into - for example - EMP table, then you'd use EMP in CREATE_ERROR_LOG.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The information is useful.

Comment: You're welcome.